# SharePoint page is not load in Teams personal app

Tags: sharepoint, tabs, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I have created a Teams app and added a SharePoint page as a Teams personal tab.

I have referred to the below link for the same,

https://aakashbhardwaj619.github.io/2020/01/16/Add-SharePoint-Site-To-Teams-Personal-App.html

My SharePoint page is not loading in the Teams app. Please refer to the below screenshot,

[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: The same issue is being tracked here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/sharepoint-page-is-not-load-in-teams-personal-app/m-p/3853833#M7930. Please follow the above thread for further updates. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in that link, there is no valuable feedback from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems SharePoint site Content URL format, Web application info section is not given as required in manifest. Please refer following video to understand the same: https://youtu.be/WAt0Dr2j6p8